# Unneeded bang(!) in HTML code

Tags: python, html

I have an issue where there a BANG(!) shows up in my HTML code@http://pastie.org/8289379 when emailing using the "sendmail" function in python below,I have read the post @ Exclamation Point in HTML Email resolution is to change it to base-64 encode the data or add \r\n on my long lines of html code,am not sure how to change the HTML code to base-64 encode?does anyone have anyother ideas to get rid of this bang(!) ?

```
msg = MIMEText("%s" % body, 'html')
msg['Content-Type'] = "text/html; charset=ascii"
s = SMTP('localhost',25)
s.sendmail('userid@company.com', ['userid2@company.com'],msg=msg.as_string()
```

Comment: Can you tell what's the result from `msg.as_string()`, instead of the sent mail in a link? Also, where's "MIMEText and SMTP" from? The imports should be included in your question.

Answer (score 2):

Some info available here: http://bugs.python.org/issue6327

> Note that mailservers have a 990-character limit on each line
>   contained within an email message. If an email message is sent that
>   contains lines longer than 990-characters, those lines will be
>   subdivided by additional line ending characters, which can cause
>   corruption in the email message, particularly for HTML content. To
>   prevent this from occurring, add your own line-ending characters at
>   appropriate locations within the email message to ensure that no lines
>   are longer than 990 characters.

I think you must split your html to some lines. You can use [textwrap.wrap](http://docs.python.org/2/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.wrap) method.